# Which is correct - "most quiet" or "quietest"?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

A friend of mine saw a gun at the store that was labeled as the "most quiet gun".  Is this correct English or is it more correct to say, the "quietest gun"?

Comment: Related: [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer:** *Quietest* sounds better to me, but both are grammatically correct.

**Long Answer:** For comparatives and superlatives (*-er* and *-est*, respectively) forms of words, always use *most* for words with words for three or more syllables. For words with one syllable, always use *-est*. Two-syllable words can vary, some with only one correct comparative or superlative but others where both are acceptable. *Quiet* is a word where both forms are acceptable.

**Source:** http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/forming-comparative-and-superlative-adjectives-american

Comment: That’s not the ***unlikeliest*** rule I’ve ever read, but it’s still not quiet correct.

Comment: Your source doesn't back up your assertion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They must have changed it on me since I posted my answer. I've updated the link. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you. _Always be careful when using Oxford comics_.

Comment: You may have updated the link but your source still does not back up your assertion. The word 'quietest' is found nowhere on the page you've linked to. Can you copy and paste the source, into your answer next time?

Comment: @JoshuaRobison the link discusses the general rule for choosing "-est" or "most", which quiet follows. The pertinent information in the article is all included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since *quiet* is a two-syllable adjetive, the rule-of-thumb would make *more quiet* and *most quiet* the expected comparative forms; however, *quietest* and *quieter* are six-times more common (or, as many would say, "commoner."  Both forms are correct, but the single-word construction is what the American ear expects to hear.

Comment: *“The funnier the post, the tireder I get.”*