# Conundrum: "cleverer" or "more clever", "simpler" or "more simple" etc

Tags: etymology, adjectives, comparatives, syllables, inflectional-morphology

I know the rule for making the comparative and superlative form for two-syllable words ending in ***y***, replace the *-y* with *i* and use *-er* and  *-est*:

*hap*.*p**y*** → *happ**ier*** → *(the) happ**iest***
*ti*.*d**y*** → *tid**ier*** → *(the) tid**iest***
*fun.ny* → *funnier* → *(the) funniest*

Instead for two-syllable adjectives which do not end in -y, use *more* and *most*:

*bor*.*ing* → *more boring*
*wor*.*ried* → *more worried*
*care*.*ful* → *more careful*
*tra*.*gic* → *more tragic*

However, there are inexplicable exceptions: *The Free Dictionary* says the comparative and superlative form of [*clever*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clever) is ***cleverer*** and ***cleverest***. Yet to my ears

> He's more clever than I thought

sounds more formal and *correct*.

Google produces a total of [15 pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20is%20more%20clever%20than%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNSgrr5NT5upKQ-6_H3N3sCCbc4jmg:1576059018862&ei=isDwXY-hNILAlAaclL7gCw&start=280&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwiPjtuvra3mAhUCIMUKHRyKD7w4hAIQ8tMDegQIFhA9&biw=1308&bih=647) for “he is more clever than” and [16 pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%27s%20more%20clever%20than%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNQYJPiJFJn2QxAMZfMDPBm2q6MADg:1576059104936&ei=4MDwXZ3oOIL1kwWviY24Ag&start=300&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwid2ODYra3mAhWC-qQKHa9EAyc4hAIQ8tMDegQIFhA9&biw=1308&bih=647) for the contracted form,  “he's more clever than”. Similarly, Google yields [16 pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22He%27s%20cleverer%20than%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNSSSDT3in1exMmH5ECKY5X7pii03Q:1576059251280&ei=c8HwXdTDENDXkwXurIOACQ&start=300&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwiUycSerq3mAhXQ66QKHW7WAJA4hAIQ8tMDegQIFRA9&biw=1308&bih=647) and [15 pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20is%20cleverer%20than%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNRUsvPlk0gfgID6QzGez-lgiCzubg:1576058638816&ei=Dr_wXcqpMbH5sAfapqvQAQ&start=280&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwjK6L76q63mAhWxPOwKHVrTCho4hAIQ8tMDegQIFRA9&biw=1308&bih=647) for “he's cleverer than” and “he is cleverer than” respectively, which suggests there is very little to choose between the two comparative forms.

Meanwhile, TFD insists that the comparative and superlative form of [simple](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/simple) is  ***simpler*** and ***simplest***. Google seems to concur and produces [17 pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It%20is%20simpler%22&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&sxsrf=ACYBGNRp7Ta0Tvc3VLVem-aaa075es0o9A:1576059612237&ei=3MLwXYOaDpvSmwWrqaKgAQ&start=320&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwiD-NPKr63mAhUb6aYKHauUCBQ4hAIQ8tMDegQIFhA9&biw=1308&bih=647) for “it is simpler” compared to only [9 pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20is%20more%20simple%22&hl=en&sxsrf=ACYBGNQlOYaLfqnMwhi9vTFtvWBj2gOaGg:1576059826235&ei=ssPwXdH4DfGIk74PyL2Q-AY&start=160&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwjRmdmwsK3mAhVxxMQBHcgeBG8Q8tMDegQIFhA8&biw=1308&bih=647) for “it is more simple”.

The two-syllable adjectives that I am aware of, which have both kinds of comparative and superlative forms are:

- **clever** → *cleverer/more clever* → *cleverest/(the) most clever*
- **common** → *commoner/more common* → *commonest/(the) most common*
- **gentle** → *gentler/more gentle* → *gentlest/(the) most gentle*
- **humble** → *humbler/more humble* (etc.)
- **hollow** → *hollower/more hollow*
- **narrow** → *narrower/more narrow*
- **polite** → *politer/more polite*
- **quiet** → *quieter/more quiet*
- **simple** → *simpler/more simple*
- **stupid** → *stupider/more stupid*
- **subtle** → *subtler/more subtle*

Etymologically speaking, is there *any* explanation for this?  Is it a recent trend?  It seems to me that the number of two-syllable adjectives that add the suffix -er and -est are increasing.

And finally, is there a trick or rule which I can teach my advanced private students? With younger learners and beginners I teach the “rule” that I mentioned at the beginning—so much simpler! :)

---

**EDIT**  December 11, 2019

I shall never ever understand Google's algorithms and how they produce their statistics. In the end, for the sake of clarity, the number of *results* have been substituted and updated with the number of *pages* each search produced.

Comment: Counting Google hits is a notoriously bad estimate for how common something is; [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simpler%2Cmore+simple&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csimpler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20simple%3B%2Cc0) shows *simpler* is fifteen times more common than *more simple*. Putting the whole sentence in doesn't make much difference.

Comment: So your estimate of *simpler* being 1.5 times more common is way off. And [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+cleverer+than%2Cis+more+clever+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20cleverer%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20more%20clever%20than%3B%2Cc0) says *cleverer* is preferable.

Comment: @PeterShor I know that relying on Google hits is not definite proof, but it is an indication, and I put the phrase in quotes to narrow down results. I know it's not infallible either, however, the same is true for Google Ngrams. They do not reflect modern speech trends.

Comment: Mari-Lou You're getting Englisher and Englisher every day!

Comment: @PeterShor that's a bit harsh to say "completely worthless". Nevertheless, the point I am trying to make is that both comparative forms are common. If someone answers my question pointing out that one is much superior than the other, I will be delighted. It makes my life a little easier.

Comment: To justify my estimation of "nearly completely worthless", the phrase "simpler than" [returns](https://www.google.com/#q=%22simpler+than%22) 1.58 million hits, and the phrase "is simpler than" [returns](https://www.google.com/#q=%22is+simpler+than%22) 12.6 million hits. But every single hit for the second phrase should also be a hit for the first. If this doesn't show these results aren't very reliable, I don't know what does. However, I think your question is a very good one, and I don't know a good answer.

Comment: @PeterShor I am not an expert on Google, I have been burnt more than once in the past, so I know it is not infallible but the results are of some indication.

Comment: Mari-Lou: I think you can add *humble* to the list.

Comment: If Shakespeare has "the most unkindest cut", who am I to disallow it?

Comment: It is explained on this Cambridge Dictionary webpage: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparatives-and-superlatives/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting - Search page for this text: "superlatives with one-syllable adjectives". - [Note: 'I am a weakish speller' is an anagram of 'William Shakespeare'. - Source: https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/396100.html ].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Swan in *Pratical English Usage* (p114) the two-syllable adjectives whose comparative form is most likely to be formed with *-er* are those that end with an unstressed vowel; e.g. *narrow, simple, clever, subtle*, etc. from your list above. Swan goes on to state:

> With many two-syllable adjectives (e.g. *polite, common*) *-er/-est* and
>   *more/most* are both possible. With others (including adjectives ending
>   in *-ing, -ed, -ful*, and *-less*), only *more/most* is possible. In
>   general, the structure with *more/most* is becoming more common. To find
>   out the normal comparative and superlative for a particular
>   two-syllable adjective, check in a good dictionary.

It is interesting that Swan himself uses *more common* and not *commoner* in his explanation above, and this seems the better choice in a formal written context. So if you are looking for guidelines for your advanced students I would recommend:

- Learn the common two-syllable adjectives ending with an unstressed
  vowel that can be compared with *-er*.
- For the rest use *more*. I suspect that native speakers are much more
  likely (*likelier?*) to consider an *-er* usage problematic than a
  *more* usage. For example, *more polite* or even *more clever* will probably sound less ungrammatical than *pleasanter* or
  *tranquil(l)er*.

If your students really would like to know word-by-word if the *-er* comparative is possible, they will need to consult a good dictionary. Swan recommends the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*, the *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*, the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*, the *MacMillan English Dictionary* and the *Collins Cobuild English Dictionary*.

The *Collins*, for example, shows *pleasanter* but *more tranquil* as the comparative forms.

Answer (score 7):

The rule that mono- and disyllabic adjectives form their comparatives with *-er* and larger adjectives do so with *more* is more or less consistently correct (unless they be participles); however, if you want a more detailed explanation, I have given one below:

There is no absolute rule, but the general trend is that any word that comes from Latin or French into English will form a comparative with *more*, whereas adjectives of Germanic origin tend to use *-er*.  Past and present participles also use *more* to form comparatives.

Obvious Latin adjectives usually end in *-ive* or *-ous*, both of which form their comparatives with *more*.  E.g. *he is lecherous* and *he is more lecherous*, but never *he is lecherouser*; *he seems pensive* and *he seems more pensive*, but never *he seems pensiver*.

The most notable exception to this is when a Latin comparative or superlative wriggles its way into English; such examples include *major* 'lit. greater (comparative of *magnus* 'great') and *supreme* 'lit. highest (superlative of *superus* 'high').  These, however, are still not formed regularly by English standards.

Another exception occasionally occurs when adjectives come through French or Vulgar Latin, such as *certain*, which has in the past formed its comparative as *certainer*, but this use is almost completely gone.  More persistent comparatives of this category include *nobler* and *gentler*, largely because of the ease in reducing *gentilis* to *gentle* and so on.

French adjectives tend to end in *-ant* or *-ent*.  Again, a man can be *defiant* or *more defiant*, but he cannot be *defianter*.  These adjectives are past participles, and so this rule is also in line with the English rule.

Germanic adjectives, however, almost invariably form their comparatives with *-er*.  *Happier*, *sillier*, *darker*, et cetera are all in this class.

Participles, whether they be Germanic or Latin, present or past, never use *-er*: *he is more annoying*, *his beard was itching more*, *the sheep is more shorn*, *the passage was read more*, and so on.

Basically, if it sounds Germanic and is not a participle, use *-er*; if it sounds Latin, use *more*.

Comment: But common, gentle, humble, quiet, simple, and stupid derive from latin, and they sound kinda *Italian* too (comune, gentile, umile, quiete, semplice, stupido) so why do they belong to the -er/-est list?

Comment: *Common* belongs to the same class as *certain*, but it has retained the *-er* comparative; it also underwent a changes that made it sound more Germanic (the Latin word is *communis*).

*Gentle* (gentilis) and *humble* (humilis) belong to the same class as *noble* (nobilis).

*Simple* comes from Latin *simplus*, which is easy to turn into an *-er* comparative; unfortunately, I can find no better reasoning.  For *quiet* I can also find no better reasoning.

*Stupid* should not form an *-er* comparative, however, as similar words, such as *vapid* and *placid*, tend not to, but sometimes it does.

Comment: I suspect that the origin of the word is largely a red herring (after all, native speakers intuit whether the -er structure is possible and don't intuitively have any idea about the original of the word). What is happening is that there is *some* overlap between e.g. the prosodic structure of a word and its origin, and so statistically, there is a chance that words with certain origins will follow a particular rule for comparative formation. But the word's historical origin can't be the *reason* for it following a particular pattern: the information isn't intuitively available to speakers.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Although most native speakers don't know the etymology, we learn how to use words from our parents, friends and teachers, so patterns and rules get passed on with slight mutations through the generations. Why is the h pronounced in hair but not in heir? Because centuries ago the coming Germanic folk pronounced the h and fewer centuries ago the arriving Normans didn't. Which verbs change tense by changing a vowel? The strong Old English (Germanic) ones: come/came vs arrive/arrived via French. The patterns are passed on through the generations. Word origins definitely play a part.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm from the UK, where [commoner is a noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commoner?q=commoner), not a comparative, and "stupider" sounds more stupid than "more stupid", and would be only used ironically. There are exceptions, but I think Anonym has hit on the most likely reason.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewC for your thoughtful comment, but commoner is *also* the comparative form for the adjective, please see the link, [common](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/common?q=common), taken from the same dictionary. As for your observation on "stupider", you may well be right. It does sound more derogatory than *more stupid*.

Comment: @AndrewC - The reason that speakers don't pronounce the "h" in "heir" is because... speakers don't pronounce the "h" in "heir". If you're proposing some model of language acquisition that relies on granddad setting you down on his knee and recounting some story about the Normas on order for you to detect and internalise a phoneme pattern... I think there's seriously little evidence for it!

Comment: @NeilCoffey You very much missed my point. I don't say the h because my parents don't say the h because my grandparents didn't say the h because my great granparents didn't say the h becuase.... (skip about 36 generations) ... because their parents didn't say the h, because the Normans who introduced the word spoke French, in which the initial h was and still is omitted. Lack of knowledge doesn't imply lack of truth; you can learn the pronunciation without learning its root cause, so we don't need anyone to know that the Normans dropped the initial h for that to be the real reason _we_ do.

Comment: @AndrewC So let's say that chain of events is true for the sake of argument... but the thing is-- and this is my essential point-- that it's an unreliable indicator when it comes to coming up with rules for the present-day situation. Take your rule and then compare the situation of, say, "hotel" (where the "h" is now pronounced in English) or "herb" (where it is or isn't in different dialects of English). Over time, analogy and other processes of language change are likely to become more dominant factors than historical origin.

Comment: @NeilCoffey The other processes of language change provide the exceptions to the rules. The origins can sometimes determine the general pattern, as they do in this case.

Answer (score -3):

The Oxford English Dictionary provides its answer [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives).

I personally prefer the rule: For 2 syllables use -er/-est unless that form is not allowed (see OED).

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO) is not the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), which is subscription-only. This is a common error.

Answer (score -5):

Okay so the simplest answer I can give is, the usage of more clever versus cleverer is relative to two things; third person versus first person, and if the term is referencing a person or thing.

For example: (From a narrative third person) Margie was more clever than Dick. 
(From a narrative first person) I was cleverer than Dick.

(From a narrative third person) "The engine was most clever" said Margie
(From a narrative first person) "I say the cleverer engine best all the other inventions".

Cleverer however has fallen out of use in modern English, except in jibe and glib commentary. Idioms from the Mid-modern English era post-Shakespeare use cleverer quite often.

Comment: This is quite blatantly not true. There is no difference in person whatsoever; _he is cleverer_ and _I am more clever_ are equally valid, regardless of narrative perspective.

Comment: Actually, as a fiction writer and screenwriter, and as a linguist, I can tell you there is a huge difference in how we tend to write first person and third person narrative. You see this distinction all of the time by writers like Shakespeare, Chaucer, and Mark Twain. Just because you don't like this fact doesn't make it incorrect.

Comment: Please do feel free to back up your claim with evidence. As it stands, you are making a claim based on nothing at all, and one that goes against at the very least four people's use of the English language. I'm not saying there's no difference in how we write first- and third-person narratives; but _as a linguist_, I can tell you that comparative formations are not normally one of those differences.

Comment: I say this makes some limited sense and the observation is notable, but I don't think you could explain it, so it is not a sufficient answer.