# "Poorer" vs. "more poor"

Tags: differences, word-usage, adjectives, comparatives

As a non-native speaker I am curious about the everyday usage of *more poor* in contrast to *poorer*. The dictionary dictates *poorer* as the correct form, with some allowing both forms.

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20poor%2Cpoorer&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmore%20poor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmore%20poor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMore%20poor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmore%20Poor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpoorer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpoorer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPoorer%3B%2Cc0) *poorer* is more common in books by an immense factor of 100.

Is *more poor* a colloquialism? If so, are there cultural differences? Or is it simply due to some people's lack of effort? Are there situations where you would favor *more poor*?

Particularly [this uncontested response on answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/Is_poorer_a_word_or_would_you_say_more_poor) got me pondering.

Comment: Where would you use it? Maybe in parallel constructions, as in "*the XXX are more underprivileged, more illiterate, and more poor than any other minority group in Ruritania*" (Although you could use *poorer* there, as well.)

Comment: Of course, there are also sentences like _there are more poor people in the suburbs than there used to be_, which will also show up in nGram.

Comment: @oerkelens: that indeed is by far the most common occurrence of *"more poor"* in nGram.

Comment: Thus, apart from the comparable form, there is another usage of _more poor_ in certain sentences. As to the answers.com response, am I correct to assume that, just like in many other cases, the _more <adjective>_ form becomes increasingly often used although it may defy certain rules of grammar [when to use "more" instead of "-er"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er?rq=1)

Comment: Related: [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the BNC/the British National Corpus.
For "poorer" BNC has 879 examples.
For "more poor" only 8, and they are of the type "There are more poor people in +
place".

"more poor" as a comparative form clearly does not conform to standard English. The rule is adjectives with one syllable have the endings -er/est.

Comment: But 'more fun' rather than 'funner' shows that the rule cannot be claimed to be universal.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to added that although poorer is the correct version, the reason more poor is used many times in spoken English is because of the 'r' sound at the end of the sentence. Many people find it difficult and awkward to add an er to a word already ending in the 'er' sound. Therefore, both are correct in spoken form (and very few would ever notice which you choose). In written form, it is always best to follow the grammar rules. I have, however, also seen more poor in written form. Perhaps, this is due to the significant use in spoken language that has crept into the writing.

Comment: This is an interesting point. There are not so many monosyllabic adjectives that end in "r", and of them, the word "far" has developed an irregular comparative form "further/farther", and "clear" seems to be another word where people commonly feel uncertain about the correct way to form the comparative.