# what is difference between the two comparative adjectives while used in the same sentence?

Tags: meaning, differences

Your room is clearer than mine
AND
your room is more clear than mine

Comparatives like these are many used in the same fashion such as neater/ more neat-- cleaner/ more clean etc.
Having been into English grammar, I find myself bemused to figure their differences, thereby left wondering if anybody could help me comprehend their contextual connotation,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning, but the form with ***more*** can be used for **emphasis**. The forms with *-er* cannot be used for all adjectives though, here's more information about forming comparatives and superlatives:

For words of only **one syllable**, you usually form the comparative by adding *-er* and the superlative by adding *-est*:

> - big, bigg**er**, bigg**est**
> - large, larg**er**, larg**est**

Note that consonants are doubled for those adjectives ending with a consonant and that the *e* in *-er* or *-est* is dropped if the adjective ends with an *e*. There are also irregular comparatives and superlatives for certain adjectives, these follow no rules and need to be learned by heart:

> - good, better, best
> - bad, worse, worst

For words of **more than one syllable**, the comparative is usually formed by inserting *more* before the adjective and the superlative by inserting *most*. However, the comparatives and superlatives of adjectives of two syllables can often also be formed with *-er/-est*, if the adjective ends in *-y*, *-ow*, *-le* or *-er*:

> - happy, happ**ier**, happ**iest**
> - narrow, narrow**er**, narrow**est**
> - gentle, gentl**er**, gentl**est**

For some other adjectives of two syllables, both forms are common:

> - clever, clever**er**, clever**est**
> - clever, **more** clever, **most** clever

Adjectives of **three syllables or more** are almost always formed with *more*. You won't hear people say *importanter*. Instead they will use:

> - important, **more** important, **most** important
> - eloquent, **more** eloquent, **most** eloquent

Above are a lot of "rules", but you shouldn't always rely on them. The rule of thumb is that if it looks sloppy or is difficult to read, use *more*. Otherwise, use the *-er/-est* form.

For more examples, have a look at [this page](http://www.eflnet.com/tutorials/adjcompsup.php).