# more unhealthy vs. unhealthier

Tags: american-english, comparatives

First off, I'm not a native speaker but this question isn't about the rules themselves but rather usage in the USA.

I learnt that you should say 'unhealthier' (and the Oxford + Longman dictionaries I looked up back me up), but an acquaintance of mine (native speaker) told me to change because it was wrong, it should be 'more unhealthy'. When I pointed out the dictionary backs 'unhealthier', he dismissed the issue as both being accepted but 'more' is still the preferred option in the States and that I should still change.

So what's the story? Are both **academically** accepted (this person writes/speaks in a very informal way)? Is 'more unhealthy' really so preferred in the States that 'unhealthier' becomes deprecated?

Comment: Apparently, it is not specific to AmEng https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+unhealthy%2Cunhealthier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20unhealthy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunhealthier%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The one-word form is gradually gaining currency, but the two-word form has always been more common (it's currently [about twice as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+unhealthy%2Cunhealthier&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20unhealthy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunhealthier%3B%2Cc0) as the one-word form). So it's hardly likely 'unhealthier' will ever become 'deprecated' - things are changing slowly, but if anything it's 'more unhealthy' that might eventually fall into (relative) disuse.

Comment: M-W says that both forms are acceptable: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/unhealthy

Comment: Related question, [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc) and [“More clear” vs “Clearer”: when to use “more” instead of “-er”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er).

Comment: @Rathony: yes, mine is realted to those questions, but they do not give me the answer about 'unhealthy', specifically, which is why I went ahead with it.

Comment: I consider my question answered by your comments. So if anyone would like to repost their thoughts as a question, I'll be happy to accept it. I really just wanted confirmation on whether the 'more' form was academically accepted since the dictionaries I use don't mention it, (besides the strange idea of the -er being possibly deprecated).

Comment: @Josh61: by the way, I didn't know that online dictionary, so thanks for mentioning it

Comment: @SaraCosta It doesn't mean that your question is a duplicate. But I believe an answer to your question is in the related questions. :-)

Comment: "unhealthier" sounds better to me. In this case, you also have the option of "less healthy."

Comment: @sumelic: Well, in that particular context, it really would have to be unhealthy as it was a comparison of several unhealthy habits. Trying to find 'the unhealthiest of them all' kind of thing

Comment: Any two syllable adjective can take er. Silly, sillier; funny, funnier, healthy, healthier. Three syllables take more.

Comment: @Lambie: not all two syllable adjectives can take er. We say "more basic," not "basicker."

Comment: Read my answer: I said MOST, not all. I forgot to say MOST here. Shoot me. :)

Comment: '[T]he rules themselves' are eventually dictated by usage, and 'unhealthier' is widely used. There aren't many comparatives formed from 3-syllable adjectives by affixation. But there's at least one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any source that states that *unhealthier* is deprecated or informal. What it *is* is unusual. The phrasing *more unhealthy* is certainly also acceptable, and apparently [more commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20unhealthy%2Cunhealthier&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20unhealthy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunhealthier%3B%2Cc0). I think you may be misreading your dictionaries; the fact that a form in *-er* is listed only means it is possible, not that it is recommended. Your acquaintance is correct to say that "both [are] accepted but 'more' is still the preferred option in the States." Of course, different people have different preferences, and some people may prefer to use a form with *-er* or *-est* if it exists and sounds natural to them.

It's true that most adjectives with three syllables or more do not use the inflectional suffixes *-er* and *-est.* However, there is an exception for some three-syllable adjectives with the prefix *un-* and the suffix *-y* (See slide 6 here: [Comparative And Superlative Adjectives](http://www.slideshare.net/guest1639c2/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives), or [this page](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Bracketing_paradox) that describes such words as "well-formed"). Other possible words like this are *unhappier, unluckier.*

Comment: The fact that a form in -er is listed (sans caveat) in a respectable dictionary means that a significant number of people use it, not just that it is in the lexicon. And this fulfils what I consider one condition of 'wordness'. // Good examples showing exceptions to the rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

- *Unhealthier* (American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition) (from FDOL).
- *Unhealthier* (Collins English Dictionary - 12th Edition 2014) (from FDOL) (also from Reverso.net).
- *Unhealthier* (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, 2010) (from FDOL).
- *Unhealthier* ("Evidence from Social Psychology - *Materialistic people are unhealthier*" - 2012 Presentation of F. Sarracino from STATEC, Luxembourg).
- *Unhealthier* ("... *light favours unhealthier products over quality products* ..." from a speech at the European Parliament on 16 June 2010.)

Comment: The presence of a term in a dictionary is not guidance.

Comment: @Lambie. I agree with you, of course. That's why I mentioned three dictionaries.