# much natural or more natural?

Tags: adjectives, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

so I've heard the expression "it sounds more natural" in many English podcasts but as everyone knows "natural" is an uncountable adjective, therefore "much" should be preceded before the adjective.
I cannot really figure it out why is this happening in English?

Comment: Nouns are countable/uncountable. Adjectives aren't classified this way.

Comment: You are confused with an adjective and its comparative form. There are only two ways to make a comparative with an adjective. Much is never used unless it modifies a comparative. Please see the related question, [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc).

Answer (score 2):

More is an *intensifier* here. With shorter adjectives you would say or write:

> brighter, taller, sweeter

and

> funnier, shinier, lovelier.

but with longer adjectives/adverbs/  prefer:

> more natural, less infrequently, more respected, better qualified.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, Hugh, but "unlikely" does have the inflected forms "unlikelier and "unlikeliest", but they are a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: Good comment; I'll change it to infrequentlier.

Comment: you mean like these situations happen in speaking or what ?

Comment: Written and spoken English,

Comment: Definitely use "More natural..."

Comment: I'm not sure I've come across the 'intensifier' label being applied to 'more'. 'Much' when used before a comparative adjective (much faster, much more comfortable) or adverb (much faster, much more quickly) is a secondary or degree modifier. CGEL [2002] [6.3.2] distinguishes between what the authors label the superlative marker (this is the most useful type of hoe) and the intensifying (this is a most useful tool) uses of 'most', so 'more' here would be the 'comparative marker'.