# Is it incorrect to use "more gentle"?

Tags: comparatives

Most dictionaries list "gentler" as the comparative form of "gentle", but "more gentle" also sounds correct. According to [this forum post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/more-gentle-versus-gentler.3356766/#post-17013908), it is.

---

**EDIT** March 14, 2020

Another question investigates the general rules for forming disyllabic comparatives: [Conundrum: "cleverer" or "more clever", "simpler" or "more simple" etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc). The conclusion is that, outside of words with some specific endings, a dictionary must be consulted for each case. In contrast to that question, this question addresses a specific word and the degree to which modern dictionaries are correct in defining its comparative.

Comment: Related: [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc)

Comment: The forum post you refer to is simply wrong. You *can* say "more gentle" but it is no more correct than "gentler"; there is also no semantic difference.

Comment: the comparative of two-syllable adjectives: ER or more + the adjective. A very simple rule. Three syllables must take more: more beautiful but uglier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conundrum: "cleverer" or "more clever", "simpler" or "more simple" etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc) (& other questions dealing with comparatives of disyllabic adjectives).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I updated the question to clarify the distinction.

Comment: The question now is about the adequacy of dictionaries. Since modern dictionaries are based on corpus studies, looking at how and how often usages occur, it seems to make little sense to ask for better methods of assessing idiomaticity. Certainly, dictionaries do not all give both variants as available, but dictionaries (even OED) claim that non-listing does not mean non-wordness. Are you expecting a 'league table' of results here? Acceptability is driven by what is general practice, not by some grammar czar or master rule. // Google Ngrams are general reference on ELU; you could have checked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally accepted view is that there is a nuance between “(a) the leg of the table and (b) “the table’s leg”. In the same way as there is a nuance between (a) “the more gentle detergent” and (b) “the gentler detergent”.

Although this origin is disputed by some linguists[1], In both cases, the (a)s represent the Anglo-Norman (analytic) influence and the (b)s the Anglo-Saxon (synthetic) influence. Anglo-Norman origins *tends* to indicate a softer approach and the Anglo-Saxon *tends* to indicate a more factual/direct approach.

Monosyllabic adjectives usually take the –er form. Adjectives with three and more syllables take the “more” form. Disyllabic adjectives may take either[2] but with a tendency/trend towards the analytic “more” [3] but not in all cases.

Google Ngrams for **more gentle,gentler,more common,commoner** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+gentle%2Cgentler%2Cmore+common%2Ccommoner&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20gentle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgentler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20common%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommoner%3B%2Cc0

Despite this both are correct and “being more popular” is not the same as “being better”.

[1] “More Support for ***More***-Support: The role of processing constraints on the choice between synthetic and analytic comparative forms” By Britta Mondorf

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6VA6AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=English+%22the+more+comparative%22&source=bl&ots=fJcBP8iaIi&sig=ACfU3U0CXbDPsFXFbYtt1ZawFxcEjwoXzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixirKAoJroAhUTnVwKHbX8AuEQ6AEwB3oECEsQAQ#v=onepage&q=English%20%22the%20more%20comparative%22&f=false

[2]

> ibid. König (1994:540) states that the choice between the synthetic vs. analytic comparative 
>   (...) depends primarily on the syllable structure of the adjective. Monosyllabic adjectives take the inflectional form: big, bigger, biggest; adjectives with three syllables take the analytic form: intelligent, more intelligent, most intelligent. Disyllabic adjectives accept both strategies.

[3]

> ibid Chapter 5 investigates the impact of morphological determinants and shows how growing morphological complexity is paralleled by an increased use of the analytic more-variant.

Comment: Largely after anonym's answer at the [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc).

Comment: Accepted for the Ngrams graph which quantifies the correctness of "gentler".

Answer (score 1):

An interesting (to me) side issue in the "more gentle" versus "gentler" discussion involves the potential for ambiguity. The phrase "more gentle" can have two meanings: "gentle relative to X" (where X is the object or standard of comparison) or "additional gentle." The word *gentler* has only the first meaning. So, at the outset, it should be obvious that *gentler* is an unambiguous option when you're trying to say "gentle relative to X" and that it is not an option at all when you're trying to say "additional gentle."

In situations where the intended meaning is "gentle relative to X," the broader context usually provides sufficient information to ensure that hearers or readers can quickly surmise the correct meaning. Moreover, in speech, I have noticed that many people tend to stress different syllables when using "more gentle" in the sense of "additional gentle" than when using it in the sense of "gentle relative to X." Consider this potentially ambiguous sentence:

> Patients who suffer complications from the initial infection require more gentle treatment.

On its face, the sentence could be using "more gentle" in the sense of "additional gentle" or in the sense of "gentle relative to X" (in this case, X might refer to the gentleness of their previous treatment or to the gentleness with which patients are treated for other conditions or to some other point of comparison). But in speech, many speakers would clarify the sense they had in mind by the stress they gave the phrase "more gentle treatment": "**more** gentle treatment" if the sense were "additional gentle treatment" or "**more gen**tle treatment" if the sense were "gentle treatment relative to X."

In writing, of course, no such vocal cues are available. In their absence, some writers follow a convention of punctuation to resolve potential ambiguity: when a phrase of the form "more Y" (where Y is an adjective modifying a following noun) may be misread by some readers, they add a hyphen ("more-Y") when the intended sense is "Y relative to X" but leave the phrase open (more Y") when the intended sense is "additional Y." *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) frames the convention as follows (at **7.85**):

> compounds with *more*, *most*, *less*, *least*, and *very* [are] usually open unless ambiguity threatens.

*Chicago* then gives this pair of illustrative examples (involving *most* rather than *more*):

> the *most skilled* workers (most in number)
>
> but
>
> the *most-skilled* workers (most in skill)

If every writer followed this convention, readers would never be left to wonder which sense of "more Y" the writer intended. But in my experience, a great many writers do not observe the convention—and for this reason, ambiguous instances of "more Y" are quite common. In the case of "more gentle," if the writer has shown no sign elsewhere in the book or article of abiding by the distinction between "more Y" and "more-Y," it seems to me that—in potentially ambiguous contexts—"gentler" is a better option than "more gentle" where the actual intended meaning is "gentle relative to X," and "additional gentle" is a better option than "more gentle" where the actual intended meaning is "additional gentle."

Answer (score 0):

It is not incorrect, though the form isn't just frequently used.

Examples from [this article](https://jakubmarian.com/one-syllable-adjectives-with-comparative-more-instead-of-er/):

> A: Did you say it was less hot in there?
>
> B: No, I said it was *more hot*.
>
> There’s nothing *more dull* than having to listen to him.

---

**Edit:**

More examples from [another article](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/forming-the-comparative-of-one-syllable-adjectives/):

> Here are the *conventional* rules for forming the comparative form of a one-syllable adjective in English.
>
> ...
>
> Now for the exceptions to the rule.
>
> Sometimes using more instead of -er with a one-syllable adjective is an acceptable *stylistic* choice:
>
> 1. The writer wishes to emphasize the comparison. “He promised to paint the chair pink, but when the paint dried, it was *more red than pink*.”
> 2. The one-syllable adjective occurs with an adjective of two or more syllables. “The lecture was *more dull and lengthy* than the previous one.”
> 3. It is easier for the speaker to say. “Both views may be right, but mine is *more right* than yours.” (Other one-syllable words that compare with more are real and wrong.)

It is of some note that this article says "**conventional**" and "**stylistic**", which supports that *even **other combinations** of a "more/less" and a monosyllabic adjective not falling within the scope of the exceptions listed above are **not grammatically incorrect** though they are usually avoided or advised against*, and it is no more than a matter of convention and style.

Comment: That example expressly pertains to the comparison between more and less, but the article is relevant. Although it sounds like the author is making an exhaustive list of exceptions to the -er rule, I'm sure that it isn't.

Comment: I don't think they are sole exceptions, either. Okay, I'll add more.

Comment: Please delete this answer. You haven't addressed OP's request. **'Gentle' has two syllables.**

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It sure does, but you're missing something obvious. The above examples show that the "more/less"  form may be used **even** for monosyllabic adjectives.

Comment: It's your answer that's missing the obvious something. And while your too-covert argument 'if periphrastic comparitives / superlatives are considered not totally unacceptable even for monosyllabic adjectives, they must be more acceptable for all disyllables) seems strong on the surface, it is far too broad-brush. 'Tragic' is a disyllable but 'tragicer' sounds outlandish. 'More big' sounds far worse than 'more safe'. 'More little' sounds awful. While general guidelines are available, acceptability must be on an individual basis.

Answer (score 0):

"gentler" can avoid ambiguity. For instance, the sentence "I want more gentle detergent" can be taken as "I want the amount of gentle detergent to be larger" or "I want the degree to which the detergent is gentle to be larger". "I want gentler detergent" clearly means the latter. Moreover, if you consistently use "gentler" in the latter case, then "I want more gentle detergent" can be taken to mean "I want the amount of gentle detergent to be larger".