# Why isn't 'oranger' correct even though it follows being a one- or two-syllable word for adding the comparative inflection?

Tags: grammar, morphology, inflectional-morphology, inflections

So 'orange' is either can be a one- or two-syllable word, however it would incorrect to say something is "*oranger*". But why?

It follows the rule of being adding the comparative {-er} but it is not correct. Is it because the word *orange* is being taken as noun?

Thanks.

Comment: "Oranger" is a rare obsolete word that refers to [a ship carrying oranges](https://books.google.com/books?id=D_tEAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq="from+a+St.+Michael+oranger").

Comment: ***More*** *oranger* would never be correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford Okay, but I am asking why you would use _more orange_ and not _oranger_, I didn't refer to _more oranger_  here in any context.

Comment: Look at the last two words of the first sentence in your question.

Comment: @Strikers It's relevant because a homonym could cause [blocking](http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0185.xml). In this case my comment was intended to point out that this likely isn't what's happening here so that others can focus their efforts on more productive possibilities.

Comment: @Laurel Yes, you are right, I didn't mean to give it a  _negative connotation_. Sorry about that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The suffix **-er** is used to construct the ***synthetic comparative*** form of [monosyllabic adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164654/how-do-i-describe-the-two-types-of-adjectives-terminologically/164664#164664) and adverbs.

Comment: And how about *purpler* for the same reason?  Marooner, scarleter ...  I think *yellower* is the exception for existing, not *oranger* for not existing.

Answer (score 1):

The standard rule for constructing the comparative form of adjectives is the following.

If an adjective has one syllable (monosyllabic), the suffix -er is added.
For example, red ➢ *red**der***, pink ➢ *pink**er***. If the word ends in *-e* only the letter -r is needed:
e.g., blue ➢ *blue**r***.

If users are interested, this form is called the  [synthetic comparative](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/linguistics/linginst/nsf-workshop/Hilpert_abstract.pdf)

Adjectives that have two or more syllables (disyllabic), usually form the comparative by adding *more*; e.g., purple ➢ ***more*** *purple*, turquoise ➢ ***more*** turquoise, and indigo ➢ ***more*** indigo. In standard English, the word *orange* has two syllables, /ˈɒrɪn(d)ʒ/, which means the comparative form is ***more*** orange.

In linguistics, it is called the [analytic comparative](http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/nenzinna/Enzinna_2017_EnglishComparatives.pdf)

I said in *standard* English, but there are many two-syllable words in the English language that *also* add the suffix -er.
For example; narrow ➢ *narrow**er***, quiet ➢ *quiet**er***, simple ➢ *simple**r***, and orange ➢ *orange**r***.

Wiktionary lists the comparative form **[oranger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oranger)** and defines it as

> comparative form of orange: *more orange*

Therefore the superlative can be either ***orangest*** or ***most orange***. However, in more formal writing, I would recommend the OP use the latter.

Online I found the following examples of *oranger*

- (a). *No. 1 is redder than no.2, though both are sort of orange.*
  (b). *2 is oranger than no. 1, though both are sort of red.*
- *For Bronnenkant, "A is always yellow, but Y is an oranger yellow.*
- It turned out to kinda be like egg tart (only the eggy bit) but mucho sweeter and kinda oranger.
- *The buckwheat is oranger than ever. You can see the shiny tin roof of Henny's shack below us, all rosy.*
- *“Well, your hair's oranger than an orange. You glow like a neon sign.”*

As to *why*, [@Shoe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/145763/44619) cites the following excerpt from *Pratical English Usage* (p114) by Michael Swan, in their answer

> With many two-syllable adjectives (e.g. *polite*, *common*) *-er*/*-est* and *more/most* are both possible. With others (including adjectives ending in -*ing*, -*ed*, -*ful*, and -*less*), only *more/most* is possible. In general, the structure with *more/most* is becoming more common.

For more examples of disyllabic adjectives that take the suffix -er, see this old question of mine:  [Conundrum: "cleverer" or "more clever", "simpler" or "more simple" etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc)

---

References:
*[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/oranger)*
*Meaning and Grammar: An Introduction to Semantics*
*Leaping Man Hill* by Carol Emshwiller
*The Toonies Invade Silicon Valley* by Betty Dravis
*How speakers select synthetic and analytic forms of English comparatives:
An experimental study* by Naomi Enzinna
*The English comparative - Phonology and Usage*  (Stanford University)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. However it seems to believe that "_orange_" is one of words in which the it is both as a _noun and adjective_, and because the superlative can only be added to _adjectives_, "_oranger_" would not be allowed. Also, I know colours can also be _nouns_, however, you wouldn't say "_I am going to eat a red_", rather "_I am going to eat an orange_" is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Strikers Fist things first, the superlative of the **adjective** would be "**most orange**" or "**orangest**" Your question is about the word "*oranger*" which can either be a ship that transported oranges (an obsolete word) or the colour itself. **An orange** is also the name of the fruit. Red, the noun, is  an informal term that refers to someone from the Communist party or someone who supports Manchester United. "C'mon you Reds!"

Comment: Sorry, I meant the _comparative_. Also, "_Reds_" is just slang, and not grammatically correct (correct me if I am wrong). Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers I'm afraid you are mistaken.  Reds may be slang but slang does not mean something is ungrammatical. See the thousands of instances of  ["C'mon you Reds"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&biw=1314&bih=603&ei=COuxW62xC5C9zwL0kLm4Cg&q=%22c%27mon+you+reds%22&oq=%22c%27mon+you+reds%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30k1j0l2j0i30k1l2.20521116.20530194.0.20530547.17.13.0.4.4.0.1209.2422.3j8j7-1.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.16.2444.0..0i131k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.pyaRZq3nv-M) on Google. Look up the term, red (noun), in any good online dictionary.

Comment: This is an informative and comprehensive answer. Good on you, @Mari-LouA!

Answer (score 1):

Who says *oranger* is incorrect? By analogy, *yellower* is used. The following are examples from COCA:

1 Academic Usage

> ...guru throw an orange, saw it hurling towards her--impossibly far but growing larger, **oranger**, as if it were a Hollywood special effect. She'd seen no other..

"Confessions of a Lapsed Vegetarian,"  *Southwest Review*, Vol. 93, No. 1 (2008), pp. 123-134. Published by Sourhern Methodist University

2 Spoken Usage on PBS Newshour:

> ...this planet orbits a star that is cooler than our own. It's slightly **oranger**, so if you looked in the sky, it wouldn't appear like the...

The evidence for *yellower* is larger, and I include by way of analogy as another color word of two syllables

> with your stuff, because this is, America is going to get browner and yellower and redder and whiter. It's always going to shift, nothing is going

*The View*, ABC

> Beyond Smiles Dental Care Centre, Mumbai. " Asians in any case have slightly yellower teeth than westerners because of the increased pigmentation (which is why we're darker

*Men's Health*, magazine

> ...air itself was bluer than it had been that afternoon, when the light was yellower. A friend and I were sitting atop a knoll in the Brooks Range in...

*American Scholar*, Academic Journal

> ...in the face of the Cards You've Been Dealt. Dorothy's teeth seemed yellower than Helen remembered. But everything about her seemed yellow now, like the pages...

Fiction piece in the *New Yorker*

> April's active nucleus dumped greater amounts of dust, which reflected sunlight for a yellower tail.

*Astronomy* magazine

> weeks, growing redder in the parts of the yard where red rocks prevailed and yellower where the earth had a yellowish cast.

*Smithsonian* magazine

all examples from 1994 or later

Comment: It is often the case that adjectives ending in -ow taker the -er suffix, *narrow* –> *narrower*, *hollow* –> *hollower*, *yellow* – > *yellower*. The word orange  does not, but you cite many more examples of *yellower* than *oranger* (only two examples). How come?

Comment: Thank you for the excerpts of different usage of the word _oranger_. However, I was looking more of an answer geared towards grammatical rules.

Comment: @Strikers grammaticality is not determined by rules; it is determined by usage: what native speakers say and write