# 'Evenest' vs 'most even' word usage and its history

Tags: word-choice, etymology, word-usage

When I am looking for the superlative form of **'even'** which would be ***evenest***, I was surprised that it's rarely used.
[This 'even' which means something smooth and regular]

The only source that I found the 'evenest' usage is this:

**> http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5099/pg5099-images.html**

I found this:
**evenest**

> Superlative form of **even**: ***most even***

http://www.yourdictionary.com/evenest

Etymology:
[Middle English, from Old English *efen*.] 
Source: **freedictionary.com**

Research about this word:

**Evenest**
[image: Evenest]

**Most Even**
[image: Most Even]

Does anyone have encountered this word both in a spoken or written form?

How do you perceive this word as native speaker, being used in everyday situation?

Which do you think is the most correct one in formal writing usage or informal spoken setting?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The general situation is addressed at [Which is correct - “most quiet” or “quietest”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140830/which-is-correct-most-quiet-or-quietest). But I'd say 'quietest' sounds nicer than 'evenest'.

Comment: Ngram shows **evenest** had its heyday in the 17th century. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evenest&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevenest%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ^@Edwin thanks for the info ^_^. And @Tim yes, it's barely visible in the graph (miniscule number of usage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/even), the comparative form is *evener*, which would make the superlative form *evenest*.

It is rare to encounter this in written or spoken form. I believe the reason for this is because *even* is as comparative as *perfect* is nowadays. In the past, one would make comparisons, *evener* and *more perfect*. Current usage tends to *even* as perfectly so and *perfect* as perfectly so without the need or ability to compare.

Here are a couple of examples using *evener* from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evener).

> The smoother and evener all brewers' casks are made on their inside the better, as they are thereby the more easily cleaned.
>
> The small pieces, therefore, absorb the heat more evenly, and this gives an evener action of the rennet.